# Need Optimized solution, for hiding the select box options

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

```
<select alt="cc" class="validate[required]" id="experience" name="experience">
   <option selected="selected" value="">option 1</option>
   <option value="5年以上">option 2</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="～5年未満">option 3</option>
   <option value="～3年未満">option 4</option>
   <option value="～1年未満" style="display: none;">option 5</option>
   <option value="～6ヶ月未満" style="display: none;">option 6</option>
   <option value="経験なし" style="display: none;">option 7</option>
</select>
```

I wanted to hide the last 3 options, using jquery I did like

```
$j("#experience").find('option:eq(4)').css({display:'none'}).end().find('option:eq(5)').css({display:'none'}).end().find('option:eq(6)').css({display:'none'})
```

The code is working find, but I think, it is not the standard way, or optimized solution, please give me the standard way of implementing the above jquery code.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAG7K/)

Comment: `I think, it is not the standard way, or optimized solution` - Are you actually experiencing performance issues or getting incorrect results? If not then there is no issue and nothing to optimize. If there is no issue what "correct" answer can fix the issue? `please give me the standard way` - there is no **one** standard. There is some which would perform better while others are not but most are personal choice.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Surely his/her code would cause tremendous performance issue.. Please don't suggest him/her to continue along with this code..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: You are missing my point I think. I would not suggest that but if the question is not about fixing an issue but more about code quality then maybe [**codereview.stackexchange.com**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `:gt(n)` selector at this context,

```
$j("#experience option:gt(3)").hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GAG7K/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.slice()` in jquery

```
$("#experience").find('option').slice(3).hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAG7K/4/)